In Jetpack Compose TextField, how can I remove text with a specific annotation once and for all if it has changed?
For certain words I'm emphasizing, and for that I'm putting an arbitrary annotation on the TextFieldValue.
            val text = buildAnnotatedString {
                append("TEST!! ")
                withAnnotation("TAG_CUSTOM_BACKGROUND", "@test") {
                    append("@test")
                }
                append(" TEST2!!!")
            }


Okay, the output is working as intended.
The problem occurs when I remove any part of the character I've highlighted here. For example, when I make @test into @tes.

I want that highlighted word to be a single object, so if it is modified, I want it to be removed altogether. But the result is that only the last letter is removed.
(previous)

(after delete last letter)

Even if the annotation exists, and I detect that the text in the current scope is different from the value injected into the annotation, and I want to process it, the moment the last character is cleared, the annotation is removed altogether, leaving me with no clue to remove the object I intended.
Is there a way to bulk remove text (words) specified as annotations when changes are made, such as part of the text being removed?

If you want an entire word to be removed, you can use VisualTransformation in the textfield.
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/VisualTransformation
